# How to react on Response from a form post in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to create a Login-Screen in HTML where the user can fill out his username and password. After that he sends the Data with a submit to the server which validate the data. If the Login is correct he sends back a message in JSON format with an `id`, like this:

```
{"id":"37"}
```

Now my question: How can i get this information in Javascript? I want to check the `id` and, if it's OK, redirect the user to a new HTML screen.

I'm working with PhoneGap to create a Android Application, so the only things I can use are HTML, CSS and JavaScript. To send the `POST` i use the HTML `<form>` tag, not a special JavaScript. If I test it in Firefox it works, I fill out my Username and Password and then the Message with the `id` is shown. Now I want to react on this response with JavaScript. Can somebody help me?

AJAX Code:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(login);
```

Comment: I tread it with the AJAX tutorial, but the response is never read

Comment: Could you post the code used? That would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JSON parser will recognize only JSON text, rejecting all scripts. In browsers that provide native JSON support, JSON parsers are also much faster than eval. It is expected that native JSON support will be included in the next ECMAScript standard.

`var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);`

The **optional reviver** parameter is a function that will be called for every key and value at every level of the final result.

now access the id property like `myObject.id`

Comment: @Dogbert I agree, JSON.Parse is a better option.

Comment: But how do i call it in Javascript? I dont now when the response will arrive

Comment: @Xal Xoy Give us the code you have used, maybe we can show you the method.

Comment: @Xal So do you get the response in the container with id `myDiv`?

Comment: Do you own the API? (Can you do a GET request?)

Comment: Nope, thats the Problem, i only have the interface

Comment: Seems you don't get the reply on your phonegap environment. (via POST) method. Possible workaround, try and create a service which accepts parameters via GET method -> forwards it to the other server via POST, gets the response and then returns it.

Comment: I have a solution for this problem. The problem was the async. When i use the sync mod it worked perfectly. I think that when i use the async the method is not called right. The method to use sync communication worked for me. The same Problem happened when i used JQuery. Only sync communication worked